# db2-Query to retrieve the values of a column if the values has more than one word

Tags: db2

Query in Db 2 to retrieve the values of a column if the values has more than one word.

Example: Last name: MARY JONES SMITH

I only want to retrieve column values on last name which has more than one word.

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried..

Comment: I tried to use like '% %' ; - This is fetching all the records with spaces appended example ' JIM' .

Comment: select name from customers where trim(name) like '% %' need to run it on production, looking for performance efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select * from yourtable
where trim(yourcolum) like '% %'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
select * from yourtable
where (length(trim(yourcolum)) - length(replace(trim(yourcolum), ' ', '')) + 1  ) > 1
```